# LCD displays wrong temperature

Tags: arduino-mega

Hi I have a program that does not work right as I aspect:

```
v = tempC;
h = tempC * 10;
h = h % 10;
memset(stempCA, 0, sizeof(stempCA));
sprintf(stempCA, "%+.2d.%d", v, h);
```

it works fine on positive temperature "+11.22"
but not for negative values : "-02.-1"

where is my mistake?
 thanx

Comment: > where is my mistake? test the temperature first to see if it is negative or positive. your code works for positive temperatures only.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that -1%10=-1, not 9 as you would like. I use

```
if (tempC<0) {print'-';tempC=-tempC;};
print tempC as usual for positive numbers
```

Comment: no , I put it in a Buffer for LCD display, I don't use print :                                                                 sprintf(Buffer2, "U:%s A:%s",  stempCU, stempCA);

Comment: Got i myself:                                                                                                      sprintf(stempCA, "%+.2d.%d", v, abs(h));